# Filtering a UNION ALL selection

Tags: php, mysql, union

I have the following code:

```
$variable = @mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT * 
FROM
(
SELECT `question_text`, `posted` FROM `questions` 
WHERE `interest` = '$interests_following'
UNION ALL
SELECT `article_title`, `posted` FROM `articles` 
WHERE `interest_id` = '$interestid'
UNION ALL
SELECT `interest_pic_title`, `posted` FROM `interest_pictures` 
WHERE `interest_id` = '$interestid'
) t
ORDER BY posted DESC LIMIT 1
```

this groups `question_text`, `article_title` and `interest_pic_title` and orders them by `posted` (a timestamp) and displays the newest

I now wish to display a small image (for example a question mark in html when the result is `question_text`) next to the result to show what type it is, how can I filter it to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may add an extra column, which would hold a static variable.

See an example bellow.

```php
$variable = @mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT * 
FROM
(
SELECT 'question' as type, `question_text`, `posted` FROM `questions` 
WHERE `interest` = '$interests_following'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'article' as type, `article_title`, `posted` FROM `articles` 
WHERE `interest_id` = '$interestid'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'interest_picture' as type, `interest_pic_title`, `posted` FROM `interest_pictures` 
WHERE `interest_id` = '$interestid'
) t
ORDER BY posted DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I'd be aiming to do this for all three and displaying images for each, would I need to add a column into the database for each? and would this cause a lot of unnecessary data?

Comment: You do not need to add any column to database.
Just add any symbol into SQL statement.
When you write 'SELECT posted FROM questions' you may write 'SELECT "my nickname is mobile" AS type, posted FROM questions' and in PHP you will see a record with two fields 'type' and 'posted', where type would be "my nickname is mobile" and posted some timestamp. You may add any data this way, and no extra data needs to be written to database.

Answer (score 0):

What is your application? I mean u want this:

HTML <-> MYSQL

But what is between html and mysql? Php? A web-framework?

Edit: i dont know PhP, but

you can create another sqlQuery that gives u a table with "question-text" only

for example

```
SELECT question-text FROM .....
```

and then in php you could do something like

pseudocode:

```
if("question-text" != null){

   print <image src="..."> </image>    //Php with html code

}
```